# Enrutamiento a web-inf en app web

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp

Estoy realizando una app web con jsp en NetBeans, necesito validar la sesión para que el sistema no permita entrar a otras paginas poniendo como tal la ruta en la barra de navegación sin antes haber iniciado sesión, alguien me dijo que la carpeta de web-inf en una app web no  puede ser accedida directamente por el usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Forzosamente necesita ser redireccionado desde un Servlet,asi que esto podria evitarme validar la sesion al principio de cada pagina no ?.Entonces  mi pregunta es:
¿Como redirecciono? Si uso `response.sendRedirect("web-inf/home.jsp");` marca error por que no encuentra el archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los archivos que se encuentran dentro de la carpeta WEB-INF son ocultos para los clientes de la aplicación. Por ende, si pones tus archivos JSP dentro de la carpeta WEB-INF no puedes redireccionar a ellos. El método [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) va a generar una respuesta con cabecera 302, con un enlace a la URL a la cual se desea navegar y sin contenido en su cuerpo.

Puesto que es un Servlet el que sirve la petición para acceder al JSP, el Servlet debe estar sirviendo a una URL. Entonces, realiza el redirect a la URL del Servlet. Imaginando que tienes el siguiente Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/home.html") // <-- mira la ruta
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/home.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }
}
```

Entonces en el servlet donde vas a realizar el redirect, deberías tener un código como el que sigue:

```
response.sendRedirect("/home.html"); // <-- mira la ruta
```

---

Tu problema real es este:

> necesito validar la sesión para que el sistema no permita entrar a otras paginas poniendo como tal la ruta en la barra de navegación sin antes haber iniciado sesión

Lo que necesitas es tener un [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). Estas clases sirven para decorar las peticiones atendidas por los servlets. Permiten ejecutar operaciones antes y después de atender la ejecución por sí sola y permite aplicar la validación a un grupo de urls. Estos se configuran con la anotación `WebFilter`.

Aquí un ejemplo básico de uso de un ServletFilter para validar si existe sesión de usuario:

```
@WebFilter("/*") //todas las URLs de la aplicación
public class MiFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) {
        //para iniciar recursos a utilizar...
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        //el método que realiza la magia

        //primero el antes de
        //lo usaremos para validar si existe sesión de usuario
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        //validamos si existe el atributo usuario
        //si tu usuario lo has registrado en sesión con otro nombre
        //deberás cambiarlo aquí
        if (!esPeticionValida(req)
            && session.getAttribute("usuario") != null) {
            //continuar con la cadena de atención de la petición (request)
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            //el usuario no ha iniciado sesión
            //mandarlo a la página inicial
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.sendRedirect("/index.html");
        }

        //después de atender la petición
    }

    private boolean esPeticionValida(HttpServletRequest req) {
        //validamos la url
        boolean result = true;
        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        //solo validamos las peticiones que sean a recursos HTML
        //y que sean distintas a la página inicial
        if (uri.endsWith("html") && !uri.equals("index.html")) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //para limpiar recursos utilizados...
    }
}
```